# How to change box color in Material UI

Tags: material-ui

I'm quite new in webdevelopment. With that said, I'm trying to change the box color using Material-UI but it's not working. (color=success.main)

Currently, the color that I'm getting is the primary blue. I've tried to change every box component but It didn't really work for any of them.

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { palette } from '@material-ui/system';
import {
  AppBar,
  Toolbar, 
  Box,
  Link,
  Hidden
} from '@material-ui/core';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import './Navbar.css';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  links: {
    padding: '0 50px',
    color: 'white',
    "&:hover": {
      textDecorationColor: "green",
      cursor:'pointer'
    }
  },
});

export default function Navbar() {
  const Navbar = useStyles();
  return(
    <Box component='nav' color="success.main">
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          VK Design 
          <Box m='auto'>
            <Hidden only='xs'>
              <typography><Link className={Navbar.links} underline='hover'>HOME</Link></typography>
              <typography><Link className={Navbar.links} underline='hover'>PORTFOLIO</Link></typography>
              <typography><Link className={Navbar.links} underline='hover'>ABOUT</Link></typography>
              <typography><Link className={Navbar.links} underline='hover'>CONTACT</Link></typography>
            </Hidden>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should define a class to set color for .
You should try:

```js
...
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main
    },
    links: {
      padding: '0 50px',
      color: 'white',
      "&:hover": {
        textDecorationColor: "green",
        cursor:'pointer'
      }
    },

  }));
export default function Navbar() {
const Navbar = useStyles();
    return(
        <Box component='nav' className={Navbar.root}>
            ...
        </Box>
    )
};
```

Comment: It didn't work inside the box component but it did inside the Toolbar. 
Is this the right way though? It seems like I'm just doing a work around to solve this problem.

Comment: What do you want to change inside the box component @KajiyamaVK?

Comment: The box background color. It worked already. Your idea lead me to the solution - I put the attribute backgroundColor but instead working inside the BOX tag, it did in the APPBAR tag. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 27):

Use "bgcolor" instead of "color"

```
<Box        
    bgcolor="primary.main"        
  > ... </Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to access the theme object using sx and then decide what color you wnat your Box to have accoridng to theme mode

```
                <Box 
                    sx={{
                        backgroundColor: (theme) => theme.palette.mode === "light"
                            ? "#f5f5f5"
                            : "#0f0f0f",
                    }}>
                    {children}
                </Box>
```